# Rabbitmq, convert send and receive message

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have seen that in Spring AMQP we use the folliwing structure:

```
String response = (String) template.convertSendAndReceive("query-example-2",message);
```

To get response about, is user took the message. How can use this structure in java without spring framework. My producer class

```
public class EmitLogDirect {

  private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "direct_logs";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

      factory.setHost("localhost");

      System.out.println("host: "+factory.getVirtualHost());
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, BuiltinExchangeType.DIRECT);

    String severity = getSeverity(argv);
    String message = getMessage(argv);

    channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, severity, null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + severity + "':'" + message + "'");

    channel.close();
    connection.close();
  }
```